# Which Exchange scenario should I choose

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, exchange, domain, microsoft-office-365

We currently have a Windows 2003 domain and an Exchange 2007 server integrated into the domain. Since the power goes out often in the current building, we would like to move the Exchange server to the cloud (Office 365) and I am wondering what is the best way to do this..

First, is it possible to connect the Office 365 Exchange server to our DC using a tunnel? If so, my concern is that if the power goes out again, the DC will be down and therefore the Exchange will go down as well. Therefore, is it possible to set up a secondary DC in the cloud that will sync with our current DC?

My last question is, would it be possible to set up the secondary DC as a Windows 2008 R2 server, given that our current DC is Windows 2003?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure select/all mailboxes for use in Office 365 and it will use your domain controller(s) as directory lookups. This means if the power goes out, cached lookup data will be used so it will have a varied impact and ultimately prevent mail flow until power is restored. You can have a 2003 domain but will need at least one 2008+ server for Federated Services. You could also have a 'cloud domain controller' but not part of Office 365, you would just be renting cycles on a virtual machine (IaaS).

You absolutely can add a 2008 R2 DC to your environment, but you won't be able to raise your domain or forest modes and take advantage of new features (such as Active Directory Recycle Bin) until you ONLY have 2008 R2 domain controllers.

Comment: Small correction, you can only raise your domain to 2008 R2 when 2008 R2 DC's are your lowest level DCs.  All else being equal, his domain upgrade path should be to add a pair of 2012 or 2016 DCs, retire the 2003 box, then upgrade the functional level.

Answer (score 1):

So a few notes:

- Exchange 2007 is not supported for hybrid configuration.  Your options would be to upgrade first to Exchange 2010 or higher, or to do a manual cut-over of mailbox data.  If you don't need/don't care about the existing mailboxes, you can just cut over your mail records.
- If you use AD Connect synchronization and use ADFS for authentication, then your access to mailboxes will be limited by the ability to reach the ADFS servers.
- As long as your MX records are pointed at the O365 servers, then mail flow will not be impacted by any outage by your DCs/ADFS servers
- AD Connect will work on 2003 functional forest/AD schema.  That said I highly recommend upgrading to a minimum of Server 2008 R2 for schema and functional level.  Server 2008 R2 will allow you to manage your AD objects using PowerShell which is very powerful.  *(Side note, you can get the benefit of PowerShell by adding at least one 2008 R2 DC without needing to upgrade the functional level.  I can't remember if you need a schema update)*

Comment: Another reason to upgrade to 2008 R2 (minimum) DCs is to remove unsupported servers from the environment.  2003 Server is EOL and, as such, represents a fairly serious security liability.